# UIPopovercontroller not dismissing from UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to dismiss a `UIPopoverController`, it works normally. 
However if the `UIPopoverController` is created from a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` action. 
It doesn't work. I have a delegate which is calling the `dismissAllPopovers`. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleChangeColor:)];
        longTap.minimumPressDuration = 0.6;
        [button addGestureRecognizer:longTap];

- (void)handleChangeColor:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    ColorPicker *colorPicker = [[ColorPicker alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    colorPicker.delegate2 = self;
    colorPicker.navigationItem.title = [Language get:@"Button Color"];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:colorPicker];

    self.selectColorPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
    self.selectColorPop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 390);
    self.selectColorPop.delegate = self;
    colorPicker.myPop = self.selectColorPop;
    [self.selectColorPop presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:scrollView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
    [self.selectColorPop setPassthroughViews:nil];
}

- (void) dismissAllPopOvers
{
    if (self.selectColorPop != nil)
    {
        //[self.selectColorPop.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:self.selectColorPop];
        [self.selectColorPop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.selectColorPop = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Place an NSLog in `handleChangeColor:`. I believe it's being called once when it passes the long press threshold and also when the press ends. Giving you two popovers.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Under handleChangeColor: 
I should

```
if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state) {
        // Called on start of gesture, do work here
        [self doSomething];
    }

    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged == gesture.state) {
        // Do repeated work here (repeats continuously) while finger is down
    }

    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == gesture.state) {
        // Do end work here when finger is lifted
    }
```